# Join Performance Not Good enough - Oracle SQL Query Optimisation

Tags: oracle, performance, query-optimization

I am investigating a problem where our application takes too much time to get data from Oracle Database. In my investigation, I found that the slowness of the query traces to the join between tables and because of the aggregate function- SUM.
This may look simple but I am not a good with SQL query optimization.

The query is below

```
SELECT T1.TONNES, SUM(R.TONNES) AS TOTAL_TONNES
    FROM
      RECLAIMED R ,
      (SELECT DELIVERY_OUT_ID, SUM(TONNES) AS TONNES FROM RECLAIMED WHERE DELIVERY_IN_ID=53773 GROUP BY DELIVERY_OUT_ID) T1
    where
       R.DELIVERY_OUT_ID = T1.DELIVERY_OUT_ID
    GROUP BY
       T1.TONNES
```

SUM(R.TONNES) is the total tonnes per delivery out.

SUM(TONNES) is the total tonnes per delivery in.

My table looks like
[image]

I have 16 million entries in this table, and by trying multiple delivery_in_id's by average I am getting about 6 seconds for the query to comeback.

I have similar database (complete copy but only have 4 million entries) and when the same query is applied I am getting less than 1 seconds.
They have both the same indexes so I am confident that index is not a problem.

I am certain that it is just the data, it is heavy on the first database(16 million). I have a feeling that when this query is optimized then the problem will be solved.
Open for suggestions : )

Comment: How big is the RAM cache setting? Sounds like 4 million entries fits in RAM and 16 million doesn't.

Comment: Hi BitBank, thanks for the comment, How  would I know that?

Comment: I'm not a database expert, so I don't specifically know what you need to do. Our product (uses MySQL) had a similar issue and this is the fix that resolved it.

Comment: can you tell us what are the index ?

Comment: Steven, the index is column delivery out id. Please note that the other database index where i did the second testing(with lesser time result) has the same table definition as this.

Comment: Bitbank, i asked you that because I am not sure where to see that RAM options. Can i see it through Sql developer? If yes, please indicate where. Thanks.

Comment: Compare the explain plans in both systems to see if there is any change and which object causing it slow down.

Comment: I've compared the EXMPLAIN plan for both database. The result are about right by the looks of it. The data (items in the table) is just the difference.
 I've rebuild the index to make sure they are fine, for both database.
I am also exploring the option of looking into the FLASH_CACHE and CELL_FLASH_CACHE settings of the index but I am not confident on this one. Not too certain what they do and if they have effects.

Perhaps if I focus on optimizing the query, if it can be optimized, then that will be my option to go.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the performance problem by updating the stored procedure. It is optimized in a way by adding a filter in the first table before joining the second table. Below is the outcome stored procedure

```
 SELECT   R.DELIVERY_IN_ID, R.DELIVERY_OUT_ID, SUM(R.TONNES), 
 (SELECT SUM(TONNES) AS TONNES FROM RECLAIMED WHERE DELIVERY_OUT_ID=R.DELIVERY_OUT_ID) AS TOTAL_TONNES
    FROM
      CTSBT_RECLAIMED R  
      WHERE DELIVERY_IN_ID=53733 
      GROUP BY DELIVERY_IN_ID, R.DELIVERY_OUT_ID
```

The result in timing/performance is huge for my case since I am joining a huge table(16M).This query now goes for less than a second. The slowness, I am suspecting is due to 1 table having no index(see T1) and even though in my case it is only about 20 items, it is enough to slow the query down because it compares it to 16 million entries. 
The optimized query does the filtering of this 16 million and merge to T1 after.
Should there be a better way how to optimized this? Probably. But I am happy with this result and solved what I intended to solve. Now moving on.
Thanks for those who commented.

Answer (score 0):

Are the two DB on the same server? If it's not, first, compare the computer configuration, settings and running applications.

If there is no differences, you can try to check if your have NULL values in the column you want to SUM. Use NVL-function to improve your query if there are some.

Also, you may "Analyse index" (or "Rebuild Index"). It cleans up the index. (it's quite fast and safe for your data).

If it is not helping, look if the TABLESPACE of your table is not full. It might have some impact... but I am not sure.

;-)

Comment: To check if table and query are the same/ have the same index, on each DB, use explain plan as @Naresh suggered on his comment.

Comment: Hi Fabienne, thanks for the answer, please see my comment in the original question. They are both in the same server(my local machine). 

I have not check for nulls, I will go through now.
Tried rebuilding the index and no effect.
Also checked EXPLAIN plan and they are both similar, except for data(one database data is bigger than the other).

Comment: Update: Checked and there are no nulls.